# Pass link_to from view to javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

What I want to do:
I have a GoogleMap with set of markers. Every marker must have a infowindow popup with link to showall_path from Rails for an object assotiated with said marker.

What I've tried to do:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
              var myLatLng = {lat: <%= @info.lat %>, lng: <%= @info.lng %>};
              var name = <%= @info.phone.imei %>;
              <%link = raw(link_to('history', showall_path))%>
              var link = <%= link.html_safe %>;


<% end %>
```

This doesn't really work, and I'm not exactly sure what should I do now.

The resulting code is:

```
//<![CDATA[

              var myLatLng = {lat: 38.2086, lng: 21.7439};
              var name = 357773063876883 ;

              var link = <a href="/show_all/2">history</a>;


//]]>
```

which needs some kind of escapig for var link, but I have no idea how can I do this.

Please clarify this for me.
Thanks!

Comment: by 'doesn't work' I mean that the JS breaks on this one. I tried to add html_safe wrapper to link_to but it didn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to escape the javascript:

```
var link = "<%=j link %>";
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-j